# Geoserver proxying custom tiles through a WMS

Tags: geoserver, wms, coordinate-system, proxy, tile-map-service

I have a set of tiles that I was given via disk (So no way to recreate them, they are already generated/cached).  There is a clear pattern/style to the naming of the tiles (zoomLevel-x-y.gif).  The bounds are actually configured the same way that "Google" organizes their tiles(from top left, not bottom-left. ugh).  More information on this specific format and how I request them in OpenLayers can be found http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/UsingCustomTiles

My question comes into play as I want to provide these tiles via Geoserver.  I have a client who is only able to access data and layers via wms calls (don't ask). The file system fetching that openlayers uses won't work for him (as well as being able to use a top-left origin instead of bottom-right).

So, from my limited knowledge of geoserver, it seems like it should be able to front these tiles to the users via a WMS server, where it takes the request, translates it to a file path/url, and goes from there.  Sort of a proxy functionality.  Am I completly off base here?  And if not, how can I even start to go about this?

**edited for clarity, and a bit more background information**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is denfinately not out-of-the-box geoserver material. One thought is to get GeoWebCache to read your tiles, and then do some magic with the "recombine and rescale" feature: http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/wms.html#support-for-regular-wms-clients

Or, you could try asking on the geoserver mailinglist.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but at least a point in the correct direction.  If no other answer is submitted within a week, I'll accept this as the answer.